# sql query for getting the newest call

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone point me to the right direction what i need to read? ...

I have two tables. 1st with customer id and customer name. 2nd with customer id and date of call to customer. I used `LEFT JOIN` to get a list for each customern with all calls to him. Like this:

```
1, Max Mustermann, 2019-05-22
1, Max Mustermann, 2019-05-20 (<- I don't want this row to appear.)
2, Ilse Meier,
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` to get customers without calls too.

Now I want this result with only the latest call.

For one call (to get the latest) I could do:

> SELECT * FROM calls ORDER BY call_date DESC LIMIT 1;

I'm stuck. What do I need to read about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `max()` to get a customer with the newest call. When a customer has never called there will be `NULL` in `Maxdateofcall`.

```
select 
     t1.customerid
    ,t1.customername
    ,max(t2.dateofcall) as Maxdateofcall
from table1 t1 left join table1 t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
group by t1.customerid ,t1.customername


1, Max Mustermann, 2019-05-22
2, Ilse Meier, null
```